# Java Checking .equals on a large list of Strings

Tags: java, string, list

Im trying to check if if a String exists in a relativly large (say 8000 items) list of Strings.

That's what I did:

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.size(); i++){
        String trim = listOfStrings.get(i).getString().trim();
        if (trim.equals(testString)){
            check = true;
            break;
        } else {
            check = false;
        }
    }
```

But although Im sure the String is in the list I get a false return. Is this a wrong approach for large lists?

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the code snipped without context. And yes break; is missing.

Comment: Whoa, what is the getString() call for?

Comment: Have you considered using a set of strings, e.g., HashSet<String>? This  would allow faster searching at the cost of more memory.

Comment: getString() is a placeholder for getX from the datamodel. I'll looking into HashSets thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be getting a match and setting `check` to `true`, but you aren't terminating the loop.  Then the next loop isn't a match and sets `check` to `false`.  Terminate the loop once you've found it with a `break` statement.

Comment: Not to mention you're using trim() which provokes that the comparison is not properly done. Let's say you're looking for "Hello World" in a list containing "Bye World" and "Hello World": They'll be examined as "ByeWorld" and "HelloWorld", so you'll get a false not-match, not provoked by the unproper way you're assignating "check" without returning, but by the use of trim().

Comment: I don't know what the actual type of `listOfStrings` is, it could be `List<Foo>`.  Maybe that's why `getString()` is called.  Maybe the OP is required to call `trim`.  All I know is that somehow the OP gets a trimmed `String` and needs to determine if this is the loop in which a match is found.  Additionally, `trim()` would not eliminate whitespace in the middle of the string, only at the beginning and end.

Comment: yes, sorry for the code snipped. its a list with datamodel and the strings have to be trimmed. regulary they have no whitespaces

Comment: @JorgeAntonioDíaz-Benito That's not correct. "Hello World".trim() returns "Hello World". It only trims leading and trailing whitespace, it doesn't remove internal whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return after you find a match.  Otherwise the next non match will reset check = false.

Answer (score 3):

The way you wrote that loop, check is going to be false unless your string is the **last** string in the list.  You need to return true, or put a break in there.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the last string in your list is the match, this will always return false because the value for check is being set to false (replacing any true value) once it hits a non-match.  Use a `break` after discovering a matching value.

Also, why do you need the getString() call?  If the list is full of Strings, wouldn't that not be necessary?

What I believe would be a proper fix (Assuming you have a good reason for trimming each string before comparing):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.size(); i++){
    String trim = listOfStrings.get(i).trim();
    if (trim.equals(testString)){
        check = true;
        break;
    } else {
        check = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get the false return because you didn't break the for loop when you find the string.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to store `String`s as a `HashSet`, which uses hash search and it should be more efficient.